# Is it OK to copy /etc/sysconfig/iptables to another machine?

Tags: security, iptables, firewall

This is my original server with very loose security given that it does not block all ports via iptables.

```
 /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

contents:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon Jun 16 20:04:05 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [8:607]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:1089]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jun 16 20:04:05 2014
```

this (below) is a server with a different company but it looks like it came with good security settings in.. ( allows only port 22 )

```
 /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

contents:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

this one looks alot better.

Can I simply copy these to my original server's `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and then reboot the whole system and expect everything to work ?

Comment: yes you can though I'm not sure it will work as iptables does not necessarilly use that file to restore the rules

Answer (score 2):

Basically yes, it's is the default iptable file for a clean installation, but i recommend to use a more up-2-date rules, and add some logging to your rules.

See this template for example: https://gist.github.com/jirutka/3742890